# How to autologin by altering Windows Server 2012 R2 registry? "AutoAdminLogon" solution doesn't completely work

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, chef-infra

I'm trying to set up a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine to logon automatically on startup - I have done this successfully in other Windows OS's but I'm having issues applying the same method on Windows Server 2012 R2.

The problem is that on startup the Windows Server machine will show me the Desktop momentarily, and afterward it will automatically log me out again and require that I enter my password to access the Desktop.

I'm using Chef to manage my configuration, and while I doubt Chef is causing any isssues, here is the Chef code I'm using to setup up the AutoAdminLogon (including the Powershell based method of setting up AutoAdminLogon):

```
powershell_script 'Autologin (no password entry required)' do
code <<-EOH
    $RegPath = "HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon"
    $DefaultUsername = "Administrator"
    $DefaultPassword = "MyPasswordHere"
    Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "AutoAdminLogon" -Value "1" -type String 
    Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "DefaultUsername" -Value "$DefaultUsername" -type String 
    Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "DefaultPassword" -Value "$DefaultPassword" -type String
EOH
action :run 
end
```

I've checked the registry and everything has entered into the registry correctly, also I've checked and no startup tasks are present and there's nothing in my "shell:startup" folder that would cause this behavior. What might be going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Ignoring the fact that you are hardcoding the password in plaintext instead of using data bag items, why don't you try using the `registry_key` resource to update the registry? https://docs.chef.io/resource_registry_key.html

Comment: Took a while to get back to you, but thanks for the tip! I wasn't aware of registry_key, I'll make use of that. Also, data bag is the longer term solution, I'm just trying to get a proof of concept for now and then make refinements later.

Comment: Did using the `registry_key` resource work for you? With your powershell code at least, I don't see anything glaringly wrong here. If the `registry_key` resource isn't working, something else may be going on, you could probably get better help at https://serverfault.com or https://superuser.com.